# How do I solve the error when attempting to Deploy a Webapp the first time that says "Something went wrong Please reload the page to try again"?

Tags: google-apps-script

I attempted to use the command "Deploy > New deployment", then Select type "Web app", Execute as "Me (my email address)", and Who has access "Anyone with a Google account". I got the following:
[image]

After hitting "DISMISS", the text behind says, "An error occurred. Please close the dialog and try again."

Unfortunately, with no further hints where to look, I don't know how to get past this hurdle, and would appreciate assistance. Thank you.

UPDATE
Here is some additional debugging information:

- I'm running up-to-date Google Chrome version "120.0.6099.130
  (Official Build) (64-bit)"
- I got the same result after clearing all of Chrome's browser data,
  closing it down, and restarting it.
- I got the same result running Chrome in Incognito Mode.
- I got the same result running Firefox version 121.0 (64-bit),
  although the "Something went wrong" popup didn't show, only the "An
  error occurred. Please close the dialog and try again".
- I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad running up-to-date Windows version 10.

Comment: Can you [`Browse in private`](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464) to see if the same error shows up when deploying the web app? You can also create a new file and publish it to see if it works. If the same thing happens in those steps, since this is a debugging question as to why you're getting the `Something went wrong` error message, it would help if you updated the question with additional information about your device, such as its name and operating system version, the browser that you're using in it, and other things you've tried, if any.

Comment: Thank you @Saddles. I updated the question with some debugging details.

Comment: It's good to know that your issue's been resolved! While it's odd that the authorization only appeared after you made a copy of your file, creating `a new file`, as I suggested, should've worked as well. I recommend that you consider submitting a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) if you encounter the same issue to let Google know about the unusual behavior that's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a copy of the spreadsheet file. When I repeated the process using the copy, I receive the following Authorization screen:
[image]

Once I completed the authorization process, the Webapp was successfully deployed.

I do not know why the error occurred nor how copying fixed it, but I'm posting this answer to hopefully save some other person from a fruitless day of trying other approaches when a simple copy did the trick.